# Book: an old retired warrior with a vision, a chubby general, and a couple save a fort from an army

Tags: story-identification, books

With all that I can remember from this book I have been unable to work out what the original story was.

### Context

I came across it in secondary school (highschool) and enjoyed it. Every now and again I remember random details and I wouldn't mind reading it again. I'm relatively sure the book was part of a series, but can't remember for sure. I definitely only read one. It would have been around 2014 when I actually read it. I'm fairly sure it's target audience was somewhere around early-to-late teens.

### Setting

The book is set in the medieval era and there is definitely some magic, but I don't think it's very prevalent and there probably aren't any wizards. There are quite a few different characters who share the spotlight in a similar manner to the game of thrones series. I can't remember anything at all about the villains or even if there were any specific villains to begin with.

### Story

The story more or less starts with an old man who used to be a warrior of some sorts recieving a vision that a castle, fort, etc. is going to be attacked by an army that I can't remember any details of. He decides to go towards the castle and provide any assistance he can in preventing the fort from being attacked.

On his way there, he meets a bandit (or group of bandits) and persuades them to join him by having the bandit shoot an arrow into a trunk and cutting it in half mid-flight with a swing of his axe.

Along his journey, he receives another vision and somehow manages to contact the fort and explain that the attacking force will be bringing siege towers, so they end up making oil jars to throw at the siege towers and set them alight.

In tandem with this, a man (who I will refer to as bob) rescues a woman from some harsh environments (and possibly starvation). For some reason I have an assocation with one of them wearing bronze armor. I don't know why, but they also go to the fort. (Despite this story being found in a secondary school, I think it does get mildly raunchy). I'm fairly sure bob's the primary character in this story.

I can't remember why the castle/fort was so important, nor who or what gave him the vision. However, I am fairly sure that it was in some way related to bob.

At some point the old man reaches the fort and he assists in some form of training regimen to help make the troops battle-ready.

In the fort itself, there is some leader (captain or general perhaps) who is holding the fort - it seems at first that a lot of the people there do not think of him as a very good one... though I can only really remember him being described as chubby. However, throughout the story he participates in the training regimen and is able to accrue some respect from his people. To give a specific detail that I can remember, he goes jogging with the rest of the soldiers at the fort under the recommendation of the old man.

At some point, bob & co make their way to the castle aswell, the battle ensues and bob is nearly killed (or *is* killed and then revived).

The book cover was a plain color with a single life-like picture of either a shield (or some other round object) with some carvings on it, or a double-edged battleaxe, with most of the haft missing.

One final detail being some vague memory of someone getting stuck in a trap, possibly a bear trap, in some area with a body of water either at the very start or at the end of the book, to act as a cliffhanger for other books in the series. It's possible that this memory actually comes from a different book, though.

Comment: It sounds like one of the Druss books by David Gemmell.

Comment: David Gemmell sounds familiar, I will have a look.

Comment: Yae, I had a look, the fort was Dros Delnoch and the book was Legend, thank you!
You should probably post it as an answer?